# System.InvalidOperationException SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am passing this connection string:

```
Data Source=eventsDataBase.db3
```

to this code:

```
_sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_sqLiteConnectionString);
```

when I inspect _sqliteConnection, I have noticed a few exceptions:

```
LastInsertRowId = '_sqliteConnection.LastInsertRowId' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

I am just starting to use SQLite. Is there something wrong with the connection string or are there other issues? Thanks.

PS:

This (suggested elsewhere):

```
data source=c:\Users\XYZ\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlaDiBla.Sandbox1\bin\Debug\eventsDataBase.db3; Version=3;
```

produces the same exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `LastInsertRowId` does not make sense if nothing has been inserted, so the exception is OK.

The connection string omits the directory from the file name, so the application will blow up unless the current directory happens to be just right.

Comment: OK thanks. So is there nothing wrong with the connection string in your opinion? I am just string to narrow the issue down (might have to write another SO question). Further down the line I am getting: unable to open database file. Could this be a permission issue? Thanks.

Comment: Yup...directory was missing and it was going kaboom. Thanks this tidbit helped me.